# adding a "loading" image to dynamic images comming from flickr

Tags: jquery

Is there a method for showing a loading image for dynamic images that are generated using flickr? I have come across a working version of this at the  http://community.wacom.com/ site but I have not been able to locate the code to see what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image that shows a loading gif. Then create another image and use the image load event. This provides a callback to you notifying when the flickr image is ready. Then just swap out the loading gif for the image from flickr.

Obviously you will need to change the logic if your using a json feed for the url's and iterating the json object but this should give you the core understanding.

```
HTML
<image id="image1" src="someLoad.gif" />

js
$('<img />').attr('src', 'someImageFromFlickr.jpg').load( function(){
    $('#image1').attr('src', this.src);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put two images in your page, the flickr image and a loading image (or text). You would hide the flickr image from the beginning (I think either `$(selector).hide()` or `display:none` in CSS would work). In the load handler for the flickr image you would `hide()` the loading image and `show()` the flickr image.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try using CSS to make the loading image the background image of the container for my dynamic images.

Comment: The images generate list items in an unordered list and I have tried using a loading gif as the background for each of the list items but the images animate(they enlarge) during the hover state and bring the loading image with them resulting in laggy and choppy effect of what is actually supposed to happen.