# How can I add loading text/image to images that are still loading with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image

I need to apply this to images that are selected by jQuery selector for example $("img"), should apply this to all images in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery loading image while elements loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956047/jquery-loading-image-while-elements-loads)
[https://stackoverflow.com/.../adding-a-loading-image-to-dynamic-images-comming-from-flickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178114/adding-a-loading-image-to-dynamic-images-comming-from-flickr)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do like this.

create an initial layout with the following:

1. Image that you are loading with visibility:hidden;
2. div with loading message.
3. jQuery's domready show the image and hide the div.

Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial at

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/

that you would want to supplement with an each() loop in $("img")