# MVC - Need image to come up as upload takes too long

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add loading text/image to images that are still loading with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999339/how-can-i-add-loading-text-image-to-images-that-are-still-loading-with-jquery)

I am using MVC c# and I need a please wait image to come up as it takes a while for the view to come up.

I believe I would put the code in Jquery. If somebody has a sample code that would be appreciated.
My image is called imageupload.jpg.

Comment: How are you handling the upload? Some code for you implementation would be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add loading text/image to images that are still loading with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999339/how-can-i-add-loading-text-image-to-images-that-are-still-loading-with-jquery) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485/how-to-show-loading-spinner-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this working demo which was one of my SO answer. This demonstrates how to show loading container in the center of the screen when you want to show the ajax or upload progress to the user.

**Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMu4z/16/)**